# Javascript Relative URL

Tags: javascript, iis

We have an MVC3 application in IIS7: http://mydomain.com/myapplication/

What would be the relative URL in javascript for:

```
http://mydomain.com/myapplication/mycontroller/myaction
```

/mycontroller/myaction - goes to http://mydomain.com/mycontroller/myaction

../mycontroller/myaction - goes up one level (in this case also to http://mydomain.com/mycontroller/myaction)

mycontroller/myaction - goes to http://mydomain.com/myapplication/mycontroller/myaction when running as dev on localhost but on server goes to http://mydomain.com/mycontroller/myaction

./mycontroller/myaction - was what I figured would be right, but that didn't work either!

Comment: Just omit the `/` altogether and it would look in the same level as the  original page having the code.

Comment: Sorry, re-read my Q and it was not really correct, hence the answers...

Comment: So what you're after is to get the application root? If so, jmav's answer looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing in ASP.NET MVC you can set root var on server side like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   var root = '<%= this.Request.ApplicationPath%>';
</script>
```

and use it in JS:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    
   img = root + '/someotherrootfile.js'
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just list the file name.

```
<script src="filename.js"></script>
```

If I understand you correctly you would only need to list the filename or path directory with no leading slash.